# Clang vs GCC - Variadic template parameter pack followed by parameter with default value works in GCC 4.8 but not Clang 3.5

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, variadic-templates

The code below works in gcc-4.8.2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename... Args>
void func(Args... args, int optional = 0)
{
    cout << optional << endl;
}

int main()
{
    func(1);
    func(2.1f); // converts 2.1 to int as 'optional' parameter
    func<float>(3.3f);  // Fine, prints '0'
    func();  // gcc OK, fails to compile with clang-3.5
}
```

And it outputs:

```
$ ./a.out
1
2
0
0
```

But if fails to compile with clang-3.5,

```
test_variadic.cpp:15:2: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
    func();
    ^~~~
test_variadic.cpp:5:6: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at least argument 'args', but no arguments were provided
void func(Args... args, int optional = 0)
     ^
```

Clang at least warns of the implicit conversion from a float to an int.  Fine, we can correct that by calling `func<float>` which puts the float parameter into the template pack.  So, if I comment out `func()`, it compiles fine.

I can't find anything in the standard saying explicitly that variadic template pack has to be the last thing in the parameter-declaration-clause, just that it becomes a non-deduced context.

My confusion comes from why clang doesn't like `func()` when `func(1)` is perfectly acceptable.  I can manually define `func(int optional = 4) { cout << optional << endl; }` and everything is fine (but instead of the templated function when passing `int` I correctly get the specialized `func()` in both clang and gcc.  What is clang enforcing that restricts the use of `func()`?

Comment: [works for clang 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d2184a139335a5b)

Comment: Here is what version I'm using, 

`    $ clang --version
    Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
`
and the command

    `clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic test_variadic.cpp`

Comment: Interesting.  Same command line but with version "Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-svn217640-1~exp1 (branches/release_35) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)" compiles with only the warning.

Comment: Huh.  May have to try with a nightly build or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually covered by the slightly misplaced [[temp.arg.explicit]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#3):

> A trailing template parameter pack (14.5.3) not
>   otherwise deduced will be deduced to an empty sequence of template arguments.

The template parameter pack is trailing and thus deduced to the empty pack in all calls except for `func<float>(3.3f)`, that is, they are all valid (and Clang compiles them fine [as of 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d2184a139335a5b)).

---

However, the compilers are not conforming anymore once we adjust the template's declaration to

```
template <typename... Args, typename=void>
void func(Args... args, int optional = 0)
```

Now, the aforementioned quote is not applicable (as `Args` is not trailing) and [[temp.deduct.call]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1) applies instead:

> When a function parameter pack appears in a non-deduced context
>   (14.8.2.5), the type of that parameter pack is never deduced.

(I.e. this should yield a deduction failure.)

Comment: Would you mind filing a clang bug at http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=clang

Comment: @ilektron I adjusted this answer due to the discussion in [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21774).