# Template arguments deduction for function parameter pack followed by other parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Is the deduction for `f1` and `f2` ill-formed?

```
template<class... T, class U>
void f1(T..., U){}

template<class... T>
void f2(T..., int){}

int main()
{
    f1(1);
    f2(1);
    return 0;
}
```

g++ accepts both, clang only accepts `f2`, and msvc rejects both.

Related standard wording:

[[temp.deduct.call]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call)

> When a function parameter pack appears in a non-deduced context ([temp.deduct.type]), the type of that parameter pack is never deduced.

[[temp.deduct.type]p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5)

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list.

So it seems that MSVC is correct in rejecting both?

Does it mean that any instantiation of the templates will be ill-formed, even if you specify the template args explicitly?

```
f1<int>(1, 2); // ill-formed?
f2<int>(1, 2); // ill-formed?
```

If that's the case, why allow such declarations at first place?

Answer (score 2):

There's a DR for this specific issue [DR1388](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1388). Aparently, it seems that GCC and CLANG haven't implemented it yet [CLANG DR1388](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html).

> Does it mean that any instantiation of the templates will be
>   ill-formed, even if you specify the template args explicitly?
>
> ```
> f1<int>(1, 2); // ill-formed?
> f2<int>(1, 2); // ill-formed?
> ```
>
> If that's the case, why allow such declarations at first place?

No if you specify explicitly the template arguments, no deduction occurs and as such the code showed above is legal.

Comment: I think the resolution is still flawed - a parameter pack is conceptually infinite, you can't explicitly specify *all* the arguments, that means there's always parameters need to be deduced, and since it's in a non-deduced context, the rest of parameter pack is never deduced.

Comment: @Jamboree You said it your self "it's a non-deduced context" however if you specify the arguments of the pack explicitly no deduction occurs.

Comment: Are these considered explicitly specified: `f1<>(1); f2<>(1);`? Does `<>` make any difference here?

Comment: `<>` is an empty argument list, nevertheless is an argument list. It will resolve the pack to an empty pack.

Comment: So are you suggesting that `f1(1)` is ill-formed while `f1<>(1)` is ok?

Comment: After seeing [DR1399](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1399), it's clear that both `f1(1)` and `f1<>(1)` should be ok, so GCC is correct in this regard.

Comment: @Jamboree DR1399: This issue is resolved by the resolution of issue 1388.

Comment: If you could update your answer to make it clear that all my examples are well-formed and GCC is the correct one, I can accept this answer and remove the discussion above.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this exact question myself and I've found it surprisingly difficult to get a clear answer.  As best I can tell, `f1(1)` should be **rejected** but `f2(1)` should be **accepted**.

That said:

- clang++-5.0 accepts both
- g++-6 accepts both
- EDG 4.14 rejects both

---

As you pointed out, a function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the list is a non-deduced context ([temp.deduct.type] p5):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - ...
> - A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list.

and [temp.deduct.call] p1 (amended via CWG [1388](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1388)) clarifies that such a parameter pack is *never* deduced.

> When a function parameter pack appears in a non-deduced context, the type of that parameter pack is never deduced.

Additionally, [temp.arg.explicit] p3 specifies:

> A trailing template parameter pack (14.5.3) not
>   otherwise deduced will be deduced to an empty sequence of template arguments.

so, taking this into account for the `f2(1)` call: the pack T is a trailing *template parameter pack* (although it is not a trailing *function parameter pack*), so it deduced to an empty pack and the call is valid.

However, for `f1(1)`, the pack T is also not a trailing template parameter pack because it is followed by `U`, so it is not assumed to be an empty pack per [temp.arg.explicit] p3.  Therefore, since the template paramter pack T cannot be deduced for the call to `f1(1)`, it should not take part in overload resolution and the call should fail.

---

Note that several similar questions/examples have been brought up in other discussions, but that they are all subtly different:

- The `f(0)` call in the example code of [CWG 1388](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1399) and [CWG 1399](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1399) is valid because the pack in question is a trailing template parameter pack, so it falls into the case I mentioned above.  Here is the code from CWG 1399:

  > ```
  > template <class... T>
  > void f(T..., int, T...) { }
  >
  > int main() {
  >   f(0);          // OK
  >   f<int>(0,0,0); // OK
  >   f(0,0,0);      // error
  > }
  > ```
- The example code in the discussion of LLVM [bug 21774](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21774) is similar to the CWG 1399 example, the pack is a trailing template parameter pack.  Likewise for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27303283/2669619).
- [CWG 2055](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2055), which is unresolved, touches upon a similar test case.  Whenever that gets resolved, its resolution will likely shed some light as to the proper behavior of the examples in this question.  Here is the issue mentioned in CWG 2055:

  > It is not clear that [the current wording of the standard] permits an example like:
  >
  > ```
  > template<typename... T> void f(typename T::type...)   {
  > }
  >
  > int main() {
  >   f<>();
  > }
  > ```