# Template arguments deduction for parameter type of function pointer involving non-deduced parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

This is similar to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36640883/2969631), but a more specific case. This time, no compiler work as expected.

```
template<class T>
struct nondeduced
{
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
using nondeduced_t = typename nondeduced<T>::type;

template<class... T, class U>
void f(void(*)(nondeduced_t<T>..., U)) {}

void g(int, char) { }

int main()
{
    f<int>(g); // error?
}
```

In the above example, the parameter pack `T` cannot be deduced, but the compiler should be able to deduce `U` after explicit arguments substitution for pack `T` (i.e. single `int` in this case).

The above is expected to work without the `nondeduced_t` trick as well:

```
template<class... T, class U>
void f(void(*)(T..., U)) {}
```

Because the parameter pack `T` is already in non-deduced context according to
[[temp.deduct.type]p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5)

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list.

Unfortunately, no compiler I tested (g++/clang) accept the code.
Notably something like below works on both g++ & clang.

```
template<class... T>
void f(void(*)(nondeduced_t<T>..., char)) {}
```

And again, this doesn't work on both:

```
template<class... T>
void f(void(*)(T..., char)) {}
```

Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: Someone please help me learn a little here. I would have thought that `template<class... T, class U>
void f(void(*)(nondeduced_t<T>..., U)) {}` was ill-formed because a variadic parameter pack is appearing first.

Comment: @AndyG from cppreference: [In a primary class template, the template parameter pack must be the final parameter in the template parameter list. In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from the function arguments, or have default arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: It appears that this is not clearly specified by the specccc

Comment: So your goal is for the function type to be deduced with the fixed `T...` passed in?  This obviously works: `template<class...Ts> struct outer { template<class U> void f( void(*)(Ts..., U ) ) {} };`.  @JohannesSchaub-litb what isn't clear?  The set of non-deduced contexts are *enumerated*, is this one of them?  The standard describes how to deduce `U` (see `outer` above) assuming the first args are not deduced.

Comment: I believe `T...` should be greedy under the standard -- it should leave nothing for `U` to consume, so there is no ambiguity.  Right?

Comment: Is [this behaviour](https://ideone.com/yjt6cI) normal?

Comment: @Yakk the spec says that "T..." is a nondeduced context (function parameter pack in nonfinal position) so it is skipped and U should be able to be deduced

Comment: @Yakk the second example here is unclear: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99d961020057d746

Comment: Where does the spec say that "NonDeducedContext ..." disables the "the type of its declarator-id is compared with each remaining parameter type in the parameter-type-list of A" mechanism? As I read it till now, it would expand "T" with "nondeduced-context" and compare it against the argument. But it cannot deduce, yet has expanded the pack's size by one, which would cause deduction to fail. I can't find definitive wording.

Comment: The "something like below" code does not work with gcc on coliru BTW

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It does work with gcc on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f832f6286b587a98

Comment: Ah, NVM I tested the U instead of the char version..

Answer (score 1):

By [[temp.deduct.type]p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type) one of the *non-deduced-context* is

> A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list.

Parameter packs that doesn't appear as the last argument of a template functions are never deduced, but is completely right to specify the parameter types disabling the deduction. e.g

```
template<class T1, class ... Types> void g1(Types ..., T1);

g1<int, int, int>(1,2,3);  // works by non-deduction
g1(1,2,3)                  // violate the rule above by non-deduced context
```

But changing the order of function argument even leaving the template parameters as they are, remove the non-deduced context condition and break the infinite expansion of parameter pack. e.g

```
template<class T1, class ... Types> void g1(T1, Types ...);
g1(1,2,3)                 // works because its a deduced context.
```

There're two reasons your code don't compile:

1. The order of function argument create a *non-deduced-context* which cause the type of the parameter pack **T** in the pattern stated in function **f** would never be deduced.
2. The template parameter T appears only as a qualifiers in function arguments(e.g *nondeduced_t*) and not directly specified as a function argument(which allow argument deduction).

To make the code compile you have either place the expansion of the parameter pack as it is forgetting the *nondeduced_t* indirect, as

```
template<class... T,class U>
void f( void(*)(U,T...) ) { }

f(g);
```

or changing the order of template parameters and specify the template argument on function call, as

```
template<class U,class... T>
void f( void(*)(U,typename nondeduced<T>::type...) ) {}

f<int,char>(g);
```

Comment: They are made non-deduced intentionally in the question. You can't answer the question by changing the prerequisite.