# Why is a parameter pack allowed after default arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, default-arguments

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but the following compiles and runs, and I'm not sure why. I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303283/clang-vs-gcc-variadic-template-parameter-pack-followed-by-parameter-with-defau), but in the example below the position of the parameter pack and the default argument are reversed. Doesn't it violate the rule that default arguments have to appear last? The parameter pack cannot have a default value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<typename ... Ts>
struct Test
{
    int i;
    std::string str;

    Test(int _i = 0, Ts&& ... _ts)
        :
          i(_i),
          str(std::get<0>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(_ts)...)))
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Test<std::string> t(1, "huh??");
    std::cout << "t.i = " << t.i << ", t.str = " << t.str << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This produces

```
t.i = 1, t.str = huh??
```

Comment: Isn't empty the default for any parameter pack?

Comment: yes, is empty the default value..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[From 8.3.6 ([dcl.fct.default])/4:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.default)

> For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later
>   declarations of a function in the same scope. Declarations in
>   different scopes have completely distinct sets of default arguments.
>   That is, declarations in inner scopes do not acquire default arguments
>   from declarations in outer scopes, and vice versa. **In a given function
>   declaration, each parameter subsequent to a parameter with a default
>   argument shall have a default argument supplied in this or a previous
>   declaration or shall be a function parameter pack.** A default argument
>   shall not be redefined by a later declaration (not even to the same
>   value).
>    [ Example:
>
> ```
> void g(int = 0, ...); // OK, ellipsis is not a parameter. So it can follow a parameter with a default argument
> ```

Comment: (Nit picking) This does not answer the question (which was not "is it", but "*why* is it allowed").

Comment: @Walter I think the most reasonable way to interpret that is *why, **in light of the standard**, does the **compiler** allow this?*

Comment: @KyleStrand You do, but I don't. Rather I think the most sensible interpretation is *why does the standard allow this?* Note also that the question is not tagged language-lawyer. In general, the most sensible answer to *why is such and such allowed* is not *because that's how the law is*. Unless, perhaps you're a lawyer.

Comment: @Walter Note OP's comment in response to this answer, and the fact that they've accepted it as an answer. Also, these key excerpts from the question: "...the following compiles and runs, and I'm not sure why." (I.e., OP is not sure why it *compiles*.) And "Doesn't it violate the rule that default arguments have to appear last?" (This is a question about what the rules *are*.)

Comment: @KyleStrand I knew it: you're a lawyer! ;-)

Comment: True, I accepted the answer based on the fact that this is *the law*, but now that you've mentioned it...in what cases would this be useful? I should probably ask a separate question...

Comment: @cantordust To save you some trouble: "why" questions of that sort are often answered with some variation of "how should we know? You'd have to ask the standards committee". It's possible that there's some record of discussion between the members about whether parameter packs should be permitted in conjunction with optional arguments at all, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Additionally, with C++, the committee seems to desire an extremely flexible syntax permitting anything that seems like it "should" make some sort of sense. Since it's fairly clear what the above signature means, the committee saw no reason not to allow it.

Comment: Note, though, that requiring parameter packs to come *before* optional arguments wouldn't make sense, since there's be no clear rule for how the compiler would distinguish between the last parameter pack argument and the optional argument.

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes, we are (well, at least I am...) so indoctrinated to think that because it's in the standard there is probably a good reason for it. I like your reasoning about the parameter pack. So essentially it is not so much about the fact that the default argument *is not* last but that the parameter pack *has to be* last. This makes sense to me.

Answer (score 11):

The why of it is simple. Effectively parameter packs always have a default: Parameter packs can be empty, so that won't contradict the concept that missing defaults must be the last arguments.

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to the great answer by rsp, it's also worth noting that this behavior makes logical sense. Non-default, non-parameter-pack arguments cannot follow a default argument without resulting the in the requirement that the default argument has to be specified--in which case it is no longer a default argument.

For example, if the following were allowed:

```
void example(int x=0, int y);
```

The non-default second argument would mean a call to function would need to be structured `example(1, 2);` as the first parameter cannot be defaulted. This is not the case for an empty parameter pack. Consider the following function:

```
template <typename... T> void example(int x = 0, T&&... t);
```

In this case it is still possible to default `x` by calling `example();`

Comment: What's more, `void example(int x=0, int y);` *is* sometimes allowed: it's allowed if a prior declaration already established a default value for `y`. This matches the rest of your explanation: that's the one way in which it's possible for the default value for `x` to get used.